# Inserting Media to WordPress Posts

Tags: posts, images, urls, media

If I insert an image to a WordPress docuament via "Add Media -> Insert from URL", and after submitting the URL and inserting to my post, is the image linked to my page or copied to my site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "Insert by URL" the image is loaded from whatever URL your provide. It is not uploaded to your server at all, nor is any information added to the `postmeta` table as far as I can tell. It seems to be equivalent to simple hand-writing the `HTML` into the post body.

You can pretty much work this out by looking at the page source, but I also tried to search the database of evidence just in case. I did not find any.